# Is there a postgresql SQL equivalent of Python's map function

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to apply a function with arguments on every element in a text array in Postgresql SQL queries

Lets say My text array is

```
["abc-123-x", "def-123-y", "hij-234-k", "klm-232-p", "nop-3434-9", "qrs-23-p9"]
```

the result should be

```
[x,y,k,p,9,p9]
```

Answer (score 6):

you need to unnest the array, extract the characters, then aggregate back:

```
select array_agg(right(t.w, 1))
from unnest(array['abc','def','hij','klm','nop','qrs']) as t(w);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I modified the question a bit. You mind checking out. Please consider.

Comment: @user4654: just use `right` instead of  `left`. In general it's not considered polite to change the question once you have an answer

Comment: Sorry, I really appreciate your solution. As soon as you pointed to "unnest", I started exploring it. Thanks for your inputs and highly appreciated.